# Keras Model always predicts the same class

Tags: python, classification, keras, cnn

I am currently trying to build a CNN classifier which takes a ector representing the log of an ECG spectrogram together with its class. What I am currently experiencing is the fact the model always predicts the class '1'.

Here is my code:

```
def LoadData(filename):

    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        x, y = pickle.load(f)

    xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=.2)

    return xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest

def AugGenerator(xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest):

    imagegen = ImageDataGenerator()
    trainGen = imagegen.flow(xTrain, yTrain, batch_size=20)
    testGen = imagegen.flow(xTest, yTest, batch_size=20)

    return trainGen, testGen


def CNN(blockSize, blockCount, inputShape, trainGen, testGen, epochs):

    model = Sequential()

    # Conv Layer
    channels = 32
    for i in range(blockCount):
        for j in range(blockSize):
            if (i, j) == (0, 0):
                conv = Conv2D(channels, kernel_size=(5, 5),
                              input_shape=inputShape, padding='same')
            else:
                conv = Conv2D(channels, kernel_size=(5, 5), padding='same')
            model.add(conv)
            model.add(BatchNormalization())
            model.add(Activation('relu'))
            model.add(Dropout(0.15))
            if j == blockSize - 2:
                channels += 32
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.15))

    # Feature aggregation across time
    model.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.mean(x, axis=1)))

    model.add(Flatten())

    # Linear classifier
    model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))


    model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
                  optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                  metrics=['accuracy']) # F1?


    model.fit_generator(trainGen,
                        validation_data=testGen, steps_per_epoch = len(trainGen) / 20,
                        validation_steps = len(testGen) / 20,
                        epochs=epochs, verbose=1)
    return model


if __name__ == '__main__':
    xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = LoadData('./LogSignalsAndLabels.pk1')
    trainGen, testGen = AugGenerator(xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest)
    # model = CNN(4, 6, (285, 33, 1), trainGen, testGen, 1)
    # model.save('./cnn_model.h5')
    model = keras.models.load_model('./cnn_model.h5')
    model.summary()

    print('Evaluation...')
    y_predict = model.predict_generator(testGen, steps = len(testGen)).argmax(axis=1)
    print(y_predict)
    yTest = yTest.argmax(axis=1)

    f = open('./evaluation.txt', 'w')
    f.write('model: CNN, epochs: {} \n confusion_matrix: \n {}'.format(1, confusion_matrix(yTest, y_predict)))
    f.close()
```

The generators *trainGen* and *testGen* both contain a matrix of vectors with length 285, representing the spectrograms, together with their labels one hot encoded, e.g: *[1., 0., 0., 0.]*. After `print(y_predict)` shows only ones, giving a confusion matrix of this form:

```
model: CNN, epochs: 1 
 confusion_matrix: 
 [[   0 1034    0    0]
 [   0  125    0    0]
 [   0  508    0    0]
 [   0   39    0    0]]
```

For completeness, when I converted the categories into a numeric form, I worked with this way:

```
y[y=='N'] = 0
y[y=='A'] = 1
y[y=='O'] = 2
y[y=='~'] = 3

y = keras.utils.to_categorical(y)
```

Where *y* is the column of the original labels.

What am I missing?

*Edit:* the using of only one epoch is for question purposes.

Comment: What is the distribution of classes in the training labels? If class 1 is overly represented compared to the others in training data, that might be why your network is always predicting it.